# How can I create a copy of a data frame excluding columns of type list?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (`df1`) that has 66 columns.

I want to create a copy of the data frame (`df2`), excluding columns of type `list`.

How can I do this?

```
df2 == df1 minus list columns
```

Comment: Try `df2 <- df1[, sapply(df1, function(x) class(x) != "list")]`.

Comment: @LAP I have modified your solution slightly (`df2 <- df1[, sapply(df1, function(x) typeof(x) != "list")]`) because if I used `class(x)` it threw an error: `Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'`. Duly upvoted.

Comment: Nice. I was not sure about it as I did not see your actual data. Glad it worked!

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help. I was also very careful to include the word `type` and not `class` in my question and title also because if something in R is of `type: x`, it doesn't necessarily mean that it is also of `class: x`; it is often the case that an object of `type: x` is of `class: y`!